# JQuery Droppable not accepting Draggable if created under Draggable item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a div with jquery tabs that load their content when activated. I've made the container div droppable which will then select tab index 6 when I drag a div onto the container div from outside of it. This is working fine.

The content that loads in tab 6 contains the actual droppable I want to use ... So when this content is loaded, it doesnt realise that the draggable object is already over it. You need to take the draggable outside of the container first, and then bring it back before the droppable in tab 6 picks up on the fact its droppable.

Anyone that can help? .. Did I explain it clear enough? :)

- Updated: Example attached
  [image]

Comment: Its all working good ... except when the droppable object is loaded remotely and appears under the draggable object ... seems like you have to leave the droppable first and then return ... (added an image to show example)

Comment: I'm pretty sure jQuery UI binds to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to determine whether a target is a valid droppable, and does not perform that calculation on `mousemove`. You could set up a `mousemove` handler on your newly-loaded content, then trigger a one-time `mouseenter` event manually.